# Access view controller without re-initializing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, download

Essentially I'm working with 3 view controllers.

1. Main view which starts a download. (Webview based which passes the download).
2. Modal download controller. (Tab based).
3. Downloader (HCDownload).

In the main view my download gets passed like so:

```
//Fire download
[activeDL downloadURL:fileURL userInfo:nil];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

activeDL is initialized in viewDidLoad:

```
activeDL = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
```

If I removed the presentViewController, it still downloads, which is fine. Then i tap my Downloads button, it brings up the controller which defines the tabs like so:

```
center = [[CenterViewController alloc] init];
activeDL = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
completedDL = [[DownloadsViewController alloc] init];

activeDL.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Active Downloads"
                                                    image:nil //[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1"]
                                                      tag:1];

completedDL.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Completed Downloads"
                                                       image:nil //[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"]
                                                         tag:2];

[self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:activeDL, completedDL, nil]];
```

However, it is not passing the current active download. I don't know if it's a initialization problem, or my tab issue of showing the current download.

From his github, he suggests to get the current number of downloads is to call: dlvc.numberOfDownloads which for me would be 
[activeDL numberOfDownloads].

I call this in the the Downloader viewWillAppear but nothing shows.

Does anybody has any suggestions or have worked with this controller?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with the last comment of the other answer, "Make activeDL a member variable instead of a local variable.", got me Googling and with some tinkering and bug fixing along the way I managed to get it all up and running perfect.

I declared it all in my AppDelegate.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface SharedDownloader : HCDownloadViewController <HCDownloadViewControllerDelegate>
+ (id)downloadingView;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
static HCDownloadViewController *active;
@implementation SharedDownloader
+ (id)downloadingView {
    if (active == nil)
        active = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
    return active;
}
@end
```

Calling to the class for downloading in my main view controller:

```
-(id)init{
    activeDL = [SharedDownloader downloadingView];
    return self;
}

//Spot where I fire the download
if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
    //More code here
    [activeDL downloadURL:fileURL userInfo:nil];
}
```

Lastly in my tab bar controller:

```
-(id)init {
    activeDL = [SharedDownloader downloadingView];    
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    activeDL.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Active Downloads" image:nil] tag:2]; 
}
```

I believe that's all of it. In any case, thanks to Lou Franco for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
 activeDL = [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init];
```

You are creating a new download controller, which has its own internal `downloads` array.  This library, as written, has no way to pass this information from one `HCDownloadViewController` object to another.

Tying downloads to VC's like this will cause problems -- I recommend you rewrite this code to split that apart.

To hack around it, try to create just one `HCDownloadViewController` object and pass it around.

Comment: This is why he recommends using [activeDL numberOfDownloads], to populate the current downloads in progress. How would I create that object to pass around? Any method will work as I have no interest to send to apple for review.

Comment: You have only provided snippets, so it's not easy to answer. Every time you call `[[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init]` you create a new empty downloads array.  They are not shared. So downloading from one VC is not seen in the other one.  You need to have exactly 1 HCDownloadViewController object.

Comment: I understand that every time I call [[HCDownloadViewController alloc] init], I'm recreating the view. I just need to know the best way to have that view controller object reference. And yes I know I only provided snippets, but those are are really the important info on how I'm working with this issue.

Comment: Make activeDL a member variable instead of a local variable.